# Weird problem with UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am running into a weird problem with UIButton. I have set it's background image for state UIControlStateHighlighted but the background image doesn't change I click on it. The target/selector still get called, BUT, if I remove the target/selector, then it works just fine.

Here's my code:

```
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentXPos, 0, minWidth + additionalSpacing, self.bounds.size.height)];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroud.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroudSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14]];
    [button setTag:i];
    [button addTarget:delegate action:@selector(topCellPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self addSubview:button];
```

I have been stuck on this for a while so any help would be appreciated...Thanks!

Comment: i suspect it should be like     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(topCellPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: But I don't want self, I want delegate. As I said, the method gets invoked in delegate just fine.

Comment: then check out cellBackgroudSelected.png image is in ur resource folder

Comment: Yepp, it's right there. I even NSLogged it to see if it return nil and it doesn't.

Comment: the code is in custom view!!???

Comment: can u post ur whole view code here

Comment: yes, it's actually part of a header view in UITableView. After pressing the button, it reloads the tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong type for your target designation. You want a a `UIControlEvent` not a `UIControlState` . The thing you are setting your button up for currently is garbage as control state is a very different bit mask to control event.

Nominally for a button press you want `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

```
[button addTarget:delegate action:@selector(topCellPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Im surprised the compiler hasnt given you a warning about this.